# Is this a right calculation of Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am trying to solve:

Calculate Fourier transform (on $-\infty < x < \infty $) of:

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
        1,  & -L<x<L \\
        0, & |x|\geq L
\end{cases} $$

My Solution:
$$ \hat f(k) = \int_{-L}^{L} e^{-ikx}dx = -\frac{e^{-ikx}}{ik}|_{-L}^{L} = \frac{e^{ikl}-e^{-ikl}}{ik} = \frac{2sinkl}{k}$$

What do you think, am I right?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Its a classical transform, called cardinal sine (sinc)

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: I believe you are missing a factor of $L$ in your denominator.

Comment: As long as the "l" in the last two expressions is really an "L", yes it is correct.